# How do I loop over a list which consists of multiple objects and adding their properties in a seperate list?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am creating a graph in javascript and I need to extract my data from my JSON input. the input comes in like this [object1,object2,...*, x_axis_data]
There can be indefinite amount of objects and the data can vary.
Each object has a group attribute so I can further classify them.
Each object always will have a key corresponding to an entry on the x_axis_data array.
Ex.

```
x_axis_data = [Mon, Tue, Wed];
obj1 = {"group":"first","Mon":"1","Tue":"15","Wed":"22"};
obj1 = {"group":"second","Mon":"9","Tue":"13","Wed":"21"};
```

I have managed to separate the x_axis_data from the rest of the array and now I have 2 arrays - one for x_axis_data and one containing the objects.

```
    for(var z in data){  //loop through all of the object properties
        var val_inner_lst = []; //array of the object data for current object
        group.push(data[z].group); //add the group to a separate array
        for (var i=0; i<interval.length; i++){
            val_inner_lst.push(data[z]+"."+interval[i]); //where my error happens
        }
        values.push(val_inner_lst); //add the individual array to the main array
    }
```

expected result:

```
group = [first, seconds];
values = [[1,15,22][9,13,21]];
interval = [Mon, Tue, Wed];
```

Comment: recheck your code. You are not using objects `{}` you are using arrays `[]`

Comment: Sorry, typo on my end in the example. edited.

Comment: Do you set the `interval` before hand? If yes, I might change my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store your object is an `array` and then use `forEach` to achieve your desired.

```js
let x_axis_data = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed'];
let objArr = [{"group":"first","Mon":"1","Tue":"15","Wed":"22"},
{"group":"second","Mon":"9","Tue":"13","Wed":"21"}];

let groups = []
let values = [];
objArr.forEach(obj =>{
 let arr = []
 x_axis_data.forEach(data=>{
  arr.push(parseInt(obj[data]))
 })
 values.push(arr);
 groups.push(obj.group)
})
console.log(groups);
console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```js
data = [{"group":"first","Mon":"1","Tue":"15","Wed":"22"},{"group":"second","Mon":"9","Tue":"13","Wed":"21"}]

groups = [];
values = [];
interval = new Set();

data.forEach(({group, ...days}) => {
  groups.push(group);
  Object.keys(days).forEach(k => interval.add(k))
  values.push(Object.values(days))
})

console.log(groups)
console.log(values)
console.log([...interval])
```

The above *might* work for you. But, `Object.values` and `Object.keys` [don't guarantee the same order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/3082296). That could mess up the chart and show wrong value to wrong key. So, you could loop through the `interval` keys to and get the values in the same order:

```js
data = [{"group":"first","Mon":"1","Tue":"15","Wed":"22"},{"group":"second","Mon":"9","Tue":"13","Wed":"21"}]

groups = [];
values = [];
interval = new Set();

data.forEach(({group, ...days}) => {
  groups.push(group);
  Object.keys(days).forEach(k => interval.add(k))
  values.push([...interval].map(k => days[k]))
})

console.log(groups)
console.log(values)
console.log([...interval])
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness sake, in this for-loop where you get an error, you push **a string** into `val_inner_lst` (or try to do and get an error). Using the `+` operator with a string in JavaScript will try to convert the other party, in your case `data[z]` which is an object, to a string too.

To access the value at the key `interval[i]` of object `data[z]`, you need to do `data[z][interval[i]]`

```
for (var i=0; i<interval.length; i++){
  val_inner_lst.push(data[z][interval[i]]); 
}
```